# Pygame rotate causes image to stutter

Tags: python, pygame

I honestly have no idea why this doesn't work. The rotate cause the image to scale up and down constantly. I looked around and haven't found a solution to my problem.
Main http://tinypaste.com/1c5025fa
Module http://tinypaste.com/f42f9c58

Also can someone explain why this program's box abruptly stops rotating?
Etc 'http://tinypaste.com/82b3b30e' (remove the quotes, I'm not allowed to post more than 2 hyperlinks)

Comment: what do want to happen with this angle __rotate(box, angle-angle/360*360)__

Comment: in the update I constantly increase the angle by 10 so eventually it'll exceed 360. So angle-angle/360*360 subtracts the unnecessary angles. Therefore it'll only rotate the minimum amount.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? That code for the angles will only work in version 2 (without `from __future__ import division`). In Python 3 angle/360 will usually be a float, and you'll end up canceling out your whole angle, rather than just the multiples of 360.

Comment: If you're using only integers for the angle, why not use a modulus operation instead?  That also has the benefit of not automatically casting into a long (or suffering for an overflow).  i.e. angle = angle % 360

Comment: Ok thanks I'll use modulus from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, the scaling that you're seeing is a sort of artifact of how the rotation operation works.  As a rectangle is rotated, the bounding box will necessarily be larger than the original rectangle.  See for example, the blue rectangle in the image, below.  R is the radius of the rectangle...so when it's rotated, the rectangle sweeps out the area covered by the red circle in the second image.  The bounding box for the rotation is the now the gray rectangle.  pygame has to fill in both the red area and the gray area. What color does pygame use to fill in the padding area?

The [pygame.transform.rotate](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) docs say...

"Unless rotating by 90 degree increments, the image will be padded larger to hold the new size. If the image has pixel alphas, the padded area will be transparent. Otherwise pygame will pick a color that matches the Surface colorkey or the topleft pixel value."

So, the solution is to explicitly set the color key or alpha value for the image (in your case, when you construct your saved_image surface.)  Then, when the saved_image is rotated, the newly produced image will have the padding area filled with the appropriate color.

Give it a go and see if that works.

[image]

Comment: Oh so all I had to do was pick a different color than the surface and pygame will take care of the rest :o. So self.saved_image.set_colorkey((255,255,255)). Thanks for the help.